# Storing a one to many relationship in Node.js using Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have a very simple one to many relationship where a `User` has a list of `Alerts`. For this, I've defined the following schemas:

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
    email: String,
    alerts: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Alert'}]
});
var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

var alertSchema = new Schema({
    _creator: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    value: String,
});
var Alert = mongoose.model('Alert', alertSchema);
```

Now, I'm trying to create a function which creates a new `Alert` and adds it to an existing `User` from the database. I have the following code (removing error-handling so the code is shorter):

```
function createAlertForUser(userId, value) {
    User.findOne({_id: userId}, function (error, user) {

        var alert = new Alert({
            _creator: userId,
            value: value
        });

        alert.save(function (error, alert) {

            // push it to the user
            user.alerts.push(alert);
            user.save(function(error) {
                console.log("saved");
            });
        });
    });
}
```

However, when I check the database, I seem to be saving null values to the User's list of alerts. Any ideas what I'm missing?

Comment: Are you certain that userId is already an ObjectId when it's used here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to push a whole `Alert` object to an array of `ObjectId`.

Try this instead:

```
user.alerts.push(alert.id);
```

or

```
user.alerts.push(alert._id);
```

both are correct.

Comment: Indeed pushing the id instead of the object was the underlying issue.